# Is there a hotkey for the drop down selection/information?

Tags: mac-os-x, interface, predictive-interface

I am more used to typing then using the mouse. I was wondering if there were hotkeys for the drop down list and the info button?

What I mean is what I have marked in the picture below.

[image: Array drop down] [image: Array drop down]

When I type open square bracket it appears, and I can press the down arrow to get the list. But I can't make it reappear without deleting characters, and I don't know how to trigger the information button.

Can anyone point me to how to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To open the help page just place the cursor somewhere within the function name and press <kbd>F1</kbd>.
To get the template list use the following shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd>.
More keyboard shortcuts can be found [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/KeyboardShortcutListing.html).

Comment: Thanks for that. OSX that appears to map to Fn+F1 and Cmd+Shift+k .